# Cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm really new to c# and making API requests in general, so not sure if my code is even making sense. Right now Im just trying to take the data I get from my API's URL call and display it onto a `TextView` called `testText`. I'm open to using either `RestSharp` or the `HttpClient`, whatever I can get to work.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    HttpClient client;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    }

    public async Task<string> GetResponseString()
    {
        var request = "http://localhost:51843/api/values/getMessage?id=1";
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return content;
    }
}
```

Inside my public `async Task<>` method is where I am getting the

> Cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage'

error for the `request` variable. I left in the comments of all my other attempts, let me know if i should try any of those

Comment: please strip out all of the commented code that is not needed to illustrate your problem, it just makes your question more difficult to read

Comment: Done, sorry was keeping those in incase someone thought those were a better route to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the [`HttpClient.GetAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync(v=vs.118).aspx) or [`HttpClient.PostAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync(v=vs.118).aspx) depending on the nature of the request being made. Those methods do have overloads that take `string` URIs.

For example

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
public async Task<string> GetResponseString() {
    var request = "http://localhost:51843/api/values/getMessage?id=1";
    var response = await client.GetAsync(request);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return content;
}
```

Here is the synchronous version of the same method

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
public string GetResponseString() {
    var request = "http://localhost:51843/api/values/getMessage?id=1";
    var response = client.GetAsync(request).Result;
    var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return content;
}
```

Comment: Both yours and Jasons solutions work, but now I'm having trouble when I called the method `GetResponseString();` set it equal to a new variable and tried to change the text of my textView. the error is `cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>' to 'string'`

Comment: The method is returning a `Task<string>` You would have to get it from the task's `.Result` property, but that will cause a deadlock because of the mixing of async/await and blocking calls.

Comment: I see, sorry I'm brand new to this, so is there a different way of going about this that wont cause a deadlock?

Comment: When I call your synchronous version of the method I get `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` and its lighting up the `var response = client.GetAsync(request).Result;` line

Comment: That is bevause the `client` is null. you never initialized it.

Comment: added `client = new HttpClient()'` to the top of the synchronous method, that should initialize it right? Now when its run I get a `System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred` still lighting up that same line

Comment: Well you need to debug ans see what those error are. Most probably you have a bad url or something else

Answer (score 5):

SendAsync has a parameter of HttpRequestMessage, and you are passing a string.  That's exactly what the error is telling you.

If you lookup [HttpRequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193644(v=vs.118).aspx), it requires a method and a URI

```
var url = "http://localhost:51843/api/values/getMessage?id=1";
var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.POST, new Uri(url));
```